# OCMock on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I've been having troubles to run OCMock with iOS 4.

I've read that a possible solution os to build the library, and install libOCMock.a, but honestly, i don't know how. Any help would be usefull

Comment: What problem are you having? OCMock runs fine, though I include the source in my unit test target, not as a framework.

Answer (score 4):

I also had trouble using OCMock as a framework, I wrote [an article](http://blog.octo.com/en/xcode-3-2-3-ios4-and-ocmock/) on how to solve this problem. You can also find an answer under [one of the previous OCMock questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204565/ocmock-for-iphone-ios4-xcode-3-2-3).

Hope this helps,
Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post about how to setup [OCMock](http://www.infinite-loop.dk/blog/2011/04/using-mock-objects-to-stabilize-unit-tests/) in Xcode can give you a hint.