# OCMock for iPhone (iOS4, XCode 3.2.3)

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode, ocunit, ocmock

I have the last version of [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) (1.55) and XCode 3.2.3.

I have created a test bundle target in my project. **What is the best way to use OCMock in my tests?**
When I add OCMock.framework to the test bundle, this build error appears:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OCMockObject", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref-to-OCMockObject in NotificationTests.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I also have this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, here is how i solved it :

- Delete ocmock.framework, the copy file phase, and any search path linking to ocmock header.
- check out the latest version from ocmock svn repo : http://svn.mulle-kybernetik.com/OCMock/trunk
- Build the OCMockPhoneSim target
- Copy the libOCMock.a and Headers folder in your project folder
- add the libOCMock.a to your framework and add a link to the headers folder in your target library search path.

Then it works !

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [Colin Barrett's "OCMock and the iPhone" tutorial](http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2008/11/ocmock-and-the-iphone/).

Comment: Tried to add Copy Files phase to the target, but it doesn't work for me. The same error.

Answer (score 0):

user3135374's answer mostly helped me get this going.

Additional info:

- The SDK must be iPhone Simulator 4.0 because 3.2 has a bug that makes it unable to properly run unit tests. Many people are complaining about it. I set this as the BaseSDK for my Unit Test target.
- You need to add Other Linker Flags "-ObjC -force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/path/to/libOCMock.a" to your Unit Test target or else you will get a lot of runtime "unrecognized selector sent to instance" errors
- If you want a target that has unit tests you can actually debug (set breakpoints) follow this tutorial:
  http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/scottdensmore/archive/2010/07/24/debugging-unit-tests-for-the-iphone-ipad.aspx

This thread on the OCMock forums has an example project you can use:

http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=73&p=119#p119